# Trouble booting Ubuntu 17.04 on Mac Pro (trashcan)

Tags: boot, drivers

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on a partition on my Mac Pro (~2013 trashcan).  When I boot into Ubuntu, it does the normal TTY tests, but freezes when it gets to "Started Hostname Service", displays some jumbled letters, then hangs indefinitely.

I'm using rEFInd to act as the boot manager, and I have Ubuntu 16.04 loading properly on a separate partition.  Right now, the Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 installation boots into Grub after rEFInd.  I can get 17.04 to load properly if I edit the Grub entry and add "nomodeswitch" as a parameter to starting the kernel.  But this causes the video drivers to not activate and I can't use two monitors.

Here's a picture of the screen:  [image: TTY output]

I'm thinking there's an issue with the video drivers.  I've already tried updating the drivers using the latest Gallium drivers, which is what I have working on my 16.04 installation.  But I still can't get past booting without having "nomodeswitch" as a parameter.

Any ideas?  Thanks.